Identify 80s/90s US kids movie where kid gets hypnotized by guy in VHS
I'm currently vacationing where my family used to come in the early 90's, and whenever we come back here I remember this video my parents rented for me one time: 

What I think I remember is a kid watches a VHS (I think).
In the VHS is a creepy dude in (I believe) a purple suit who's holding some kind of spinning disco-ball-like patterned thing that hypnotizes the kid.
The boy then (I think) gets sucked into the TV world.

Am I crazy or is this a real movie/TV show?*

Welcome to Movies and TV SE! Is there anything else you could tell us? where was it set? Anything about the plot you remember? Was it in colour? When did it show? What country was it filmed in? Any other characters? What did they say? What did the scenes look like? This stuff we need to know so then we can give you an appropriate answer. Good try though! Also, can you tell us what a VHS is? Some people may not know what that is.

Perhaps Remote Control? People start watching bad SciFi movie and are brainwashed by it. Video store employee discovers the plot and tries to destroy all video-tapes of the movie
There is Stay Tuned but it is about guy watching TV too much so devil sells him awesome package and he is sucked into TV.

It sounds like Brainscan, a 1994 movie with Edward Furlong and T. Ryder Smith as the trickster (the creepy guy in a suit).

I remember from the scene where the Trickster mesmerizes the young boy, here are the first paragraph from wikipedia that describe the plot:

A lonely boy named Michael Brower (Edward Furlong) lives an isolated existence in his absent father's mansion. Michael's mother was killed in a car accident, which also permanently injured his leg. He spends his spare time stalking his crush, a typical girl-next-door named Kimberly. A huge fan of horror films and video games, Michael's only friend is a similar-minded misfit named Kyle. Kyle tells Michael about a new, ultra-realistic game called Brainscan. Intrigued, Michael sends away for the first disc.
The game begins strangely, with a warning screen informing him that the experience has much in common with hypnotic suggestion. During his first experience with the game, Michael is encouraged to act as a psychopathic murderer by the game's host, an entity known as Trickster. In-game, Michael murders a stranger and takes his foot as a trophy. Later, he is horrified to discover that his victim in the game was a real person, and that the same murder also happened in the real world...

